# Not able to invoke controller's HttpPost method

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement following scenario.
Create a web page where a user can type in his/her comments in the comment text area and on the click of submit button, the web page should fire an email to client's email address and then a new View should load displaying message that user's suggestion have been sent to the client.

In my asp.Net MVC application I created a control and added a [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] method names "SuggestionMessage". The Get method loads the view to show the suggestion's form. The problem is on the submit button click my httpPost method is not getting implemented!

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SuggestionMessage()
        {
        //this view will load the suggestion form
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SuggestionMessage(string content)
        {
        //Code to send email
        //below view will display the message that the user's
        //suggestion have been sent to client.
           return View();
        }
```

This is my Suggestion form

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Suggestions";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Suggestions</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            font: 20px Montserrat, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.8;
            color: #000000;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .margin {
            margin-bottom: 25px;
        }

        .margin-1 {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .bg-1 {
            background-color: #23F0E4; /* Aqua */
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .container-fluid {
            padding-top: 70px;
            padding-bottom: 70px;
            padding-left: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())  
        {
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button  class="btn-primary" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    }
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also noticed that my post method is expecting a "string content" parameter so I need to pass this as route object in `Html.BeginForm(Html.BeginForm("PostSuggestion",MyController,new {content="example string"},FormMethod.Post)`. we also need to add a [Route(Name="content")] above my post method.

Comment: `[HttpPost]
        [Route(Name ="content")]
        public ActionResult SuggestionMessage(string content)
        {
                return View();
         }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code indicates two forms, which could be messing with the submit button and is submitting the extra form tag without any action attribute;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())  
{
   <form>
      ...
   </form>
}
```

**Don't forget to add a name attribute** to your form fields, I noticed textarea didn't contain the name attribute, use;

```
<textarea name="content" class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
```

**Your button didn't have type=submit attribute as well**, to be sure that it's meant to submit, use;

```
<button type="Submit" class="btn-primary" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
```

`@Html.BeginForm` already encloses the elements inside it with a `<form>` tag and would post automatically to the same controller and action name, so just use;

```
// just remove the extra form tag inside Html.BeginForm()

@using (Html.BeginForm())  
{
  <div class="form-group">
     label for="comment">Comment:</label>
     <textarea name="content" class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
     <button type="Submit" class="btn-primary" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your inputs I did change the type of button to Submit. Also I changed the name of my post method to differentiate from Get method. I used `Html.BeginForm("PostSuggestion",MyController,FormMethod.Post)` And finally it worked!!